# iTextSharp reading paragraphs only

Tags: c#, pdf, text, itext, extract

I am using `iTextSharp` to read PDF files using C#.
The text extraction using `PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage()` function returns all text as expected.

But for a PDF which has say, Table of Content, Index & say page number should be dropped.
And I just want to get the paragraph of text.

I checked for availability of options by exploring the `ITextExtractionStrategy`.

I am really clueless and any pointers will help.

I explored to isolate the fields using `AcroFields`, but that looks like a long shot.

Thank you.

Regards,
~Mayur

Comment: In general PDFs do not contain the information whether some glyphs belong to the table of contents, index, header, footer, or text body. iText text extraction, therefore, concentrates on the task of extracting all the text there is. If you want to have things done differently, feel free to implement recognition of table of contents, index, header, and footer, and by means of `RenderFilters` or custom `TextExtractionStrategies` remove them from the text extraction process.

Comment: I have not entirely understood the comment. Sorry. Making my own custom TextExtractionStrategies is like a Catch22 situation for me. I really dont know how to isolate the header from the paragraphs

Comment: To *isolate the header from the paragraphs* in generic documents is indeed a task involving quite some pattern matching artificial intelligence. For a generic solution, you should either first study scientific publications on that matter before implementing it or convert the pages to images and apply existing solutions working on image files (not my area of knowledge). If you only have to do that for specific documents, though, there may be patterns which are easier to implement.